# Nuget Package in Visual Studio Professional 2017

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm Going to Install the **Visual Studio Professional 2017** so that I can connect to Oracle Client 10.2.0.3 using *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll*

Does Visual Studio Professional 2017 has by default NuGet Package Installed Or I need to install it manually to get Connected to Oracle

*C# Application Developement*

Comment: If you are asking about Nuget Package Manager the answer is yes.

Comment: Did you ever work with nuget? These packages are loaded per Project/solution, if needed, into a common folder.

Comment: by default it is installed right with visual studio professional 2017

Comment: The package manager is installed. The concrete Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package you need to install it

Comment: The `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` does not need any Oracle Client.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Visual Studio Professional 2017 has by default NuGet Package
>   Installed Or I need to install it manually to get Connected to Oracle>

Visual Studio Professional 2017 has the NuGet package manager installed by default. So when you create a new Solution/Project (or open existing one) you can use the package manager to install, update or de-install NuGet packages within that solution/project. You can either:

1. Right click on the solution -> choose "Manage NuGet packages for the solution" and manage the packages for one, several or all projects within that solution

or

2. Right click on a project -> choose "Manage NuGet packages" and manage the packages for the chosen project.